# JFET Transistor Output Impedance

Tags: circuit-analysis, jfet

The output impedance (\$R_{out}\$) of this circuit is \$R_{S3}\$?
[image]

---

New circuit:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find \$ R_{OUT}\$ we need to solve this circuit:

[image]

And for this circuit \$ R_{OUT} = \frac{V_X}{I_X}\$

And from KCL we have:

$$I_X =\frac{V_X}{R_S} -g_m*(-V_X)$$

$$I_X =\frac{V_X}{R_S}+g_mV_X$$

$$I_X =\frac{V_X}{R_S}+\frac{V_X}{\frac{1}{gm}} $$

So, \$R_{OUT}\$ is ??

This method can also be used to find Rth3 in your BJT circuit problem.

And another example can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265046/calculation-of-output-impedance-of-ce-emitter-bias-configuration-unbypassed-wi/276764#276764)

Comment: Do not lack r0 resistance in the model for small signals? Why did the dependent source become an independent source? Thanks for help

Comment: @CarmenGonzález For simplicity I skipped ro resistance. But this is not a problem because ro is in parallel with Rs.

Comment: We still have a dependent source, but now Vx = -Vgs and this is why Id = gm(-Vx)

Comment: Why did \$R_g\$ disappear in the incremental model?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález because we find Rout for Vin = 0V. So we replace the Vin with a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the small signal diagram is wrong. You have shorted Vout to ground (node D should be ground). That being said, looking "up" the source, the resistance should be about 1/gm in parallel with RS3, so approximately 1/gm (provided gm is large).

Comment: I did not realize the change you want to make in the small sign model. Could you do a drawing, please? I had already been told about this change, but without the drawing I do not understand what it means.

Comment: I make a new circuit. Can you see if the circuit is well-maded? Thanks for support.

Comment: G36's answer provides the details.