# finding the output resistance of bjt folded cascode

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, resistance

I am being asked to find the output resistance of following BJT cascode amplifier, from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra and Smith, 7th edition, problem 8.80.a on page 588.

[image: schematic]

Now I decided to simplify the circuit down using the convention of opening the current sources and shorting the dc voltages to ground. Afterwards, I used the equivalent T-model to find the output resistance. I utilized the fact that the output resistance of Q1 is r_o already. Therefore, to find Ro my circuit would simplify to the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcCZ0O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is my analysis
\begin{equation}
\\KVL\quad outer\quad loop\\
v_o=r_o\left(i_o+g_mv_{\pi }\right)+r_oi_1\\
now\quad i_o+g_mv_{\pi }=i_1+i_e\\i_e=\frac{g_mv_{\pi \:}}{\alpha }\\therefore\quad i_1=i_o-\frac{g_mv_{\pi \:\:}}{\beta }\\now\quad substituting\quad v_o=2r_oi_o+r_og_mv_{\pi \:}\left(1-\frac{1}{\beta }\:\right)
\end{equation}
Here utilizing the outer loop of ro and re, we get:
\begin{equation}
v_{\pi }=r_oi_1\\v_{\pi }=r_o\left(i_o-\beta g_mv_{\pi }\right)\\Therefore\quad\\v_{\pi \:}=\frac{r_o}{1+r_o\beta \:g_m}i_o
\end{equation}
Now using these relationships and substituting, we get
\begin{equation}
R_o=\frac{v_o}{i_o}=2r_o+\frac{r_o^2g_m\left(\beta -1\:\right)}{\beta \left(1+\beta \:r_o\:g_m\right)}
\end{equation}
Here, am using the following values for the parameters:
\begin{equation}
V_A=5,\:\beta =100,\:I=0.1mA
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, am using these values and am coming up with a 100.5K ohms. I know there is something wrong with my analysis, because the answer should come out to 3.33M ohms. but I can't figure out what it is. Can somebody please point me to where the mistake is in my analysis. Thank you.

** Also, the transistors are matched, parameter values are the same for Q1 and Q2

Comment: There's actually something wrong with your small signal circuit. \$g_mv_{\pi}\$ must flow from emitter of Q2 all the way to collector, not from base to collector.

Comment: @dirac16 thank you for your comment. But this is the way my book does it. \$g_mv_{pi}\$ means the collector current. Therefore, it should only flow from the base to the collector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should notice is that from a small-signal preceptive point of view \$Q_1\$ \$r_{o1}\$ act just like the emitter resistance for \$Q_2\$

And the small signal mode will look like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1gWBE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The small-signal parameters are:

\$\large g_{m2} = \frac{0.1\textrm{mA}}{25\textrm{mV}} = 4\textrm{mS}\$

\$\large r_{\pi 2} = \frac{\beta}{g_{m2}} = 25\textrm{k}\Omega\$

\$\large r_{o2} = r_{o1} = \frac{V_A}{\textrm{I}} =\frac{5 \textrm{V}}{0.1\textrm{mA}} = 50 \$

Hence the output resistance will be the same as I show here:

[BJT common-base output resistance derivation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342859/bjt-common-base-output-resistance-derivation/342989#342989)

[finding output resistance of CB amplifier with ro](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377737/finding-output-resistance-of-cb-amplifier-with-ro/377769#377769)

$$R_{OUT} = \frac{V_X}{I_X} = r_{o2}+\left(1+ g_{m2} r_{o2}\right)\cdot r_{o1}||r_{\pi2} = 3.4\textrm{M}\Omega $$

Also, remember that in the small-signal analysis you can replace PNP with the NPN small-signal model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fccXoL.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frzfuy.png)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I would like to get some clarifications. I noticed that your model seems like the hybrid-pi model since you are using the r-pi. But my confusion now is, how could r_o1 which is in the emitter of Q2 be in parallel with r_pi2 which is in the base of Q2??

Comment: could you please point me to where my mistake is in my analysis. I can't figure out where am going wrong??

Comment: @Raykh but do you see that ro||re in your small-signal? And from where did you get this 2ro? Vo = ro(Io + gm vpi)+ ro I1 is equal to Vo = ro(Io+ gm vpi + I1)also you equation for vpi is wrong. It seems that you forget that I1 = Io - (gm Vpi)/β. So vpi = (β Io ro)/(β + gm ro)

Comment: Ah! you nailed it. It is this algebra mistake for vpi. Exactly, vpi = ( Io ro)/(1 + gm ro/β ). Thank you very much. A lot of insightful information I learned. I didn't know that for small signal analysis you can replace the PNP with NPN. Thank you very much.

Comment: given that now I know Ro and Rin for this folded cascode. Do you know a technique to find the gain Av using Ro and Rin?? or do I have to redo the small signal analysis all over again but for now to find gain??

Comment: Well, Rin = r_pi1 and the gain is the same as for CE amplifier Av = gm*RL

Comment: because we have to stages Q1 is a CE amplifier with a gain equal to re2/re1 = 1V/V and Q2 is a CB stage.

Comment: thank you. But in general, do you know if there is a way to find the gain given Rin and Ro?? Also, for CE shouldn't  Av = -gm*RL??

Comment: Usually, we omit this "minus" sign because we know what this "minus" sign represents/means. This "minus" only informs us that the output voltage is the 180-degree phase shift with respect to the input voltage. Av _max = (βxRout)/Rin = (100 x 3.4MΩ)/25kΩ =13.6kV/V or gm x Rout = 4mS x 3.4MΩ = 13.6kV/V

Answer (score 0):

i hope you *did* notice that in fact there are two different ro's going on in this circuit here... (I'm assuming based on context that you have VAnpn = VApnp which is really nice but I get it it's a textbook problem, ) ... so go back to the drawing board and redo your KVL's and KCL's. by the way, save yourself some time, choose KCL over KVL 99% of the time for these problems... they just end up being fewer more succinct/compact equations to solve.  (personal experience)

i also suspect your small signal model for your pnp transistor should be checked... i just did a cursory inspection and I bet dirac16 is right

Comment: You could have saved yourself the time than giving me a "smart" answer. You're answer is irrelevant to the question and does not imply helpful information, sorry voting down.