# PNP folded cascode circuit question

Tags: bjt, pnp

[image]I have a homework question but no idea what this circuit does and how to make calculations. In the simulation input and output voltages are same why?

Thanks for any help

Comment: But a  folded cascode is a PNP and NPN circuit or NPN-PNP circuit. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380184/finding-the-output-resistance-of-bjt-folded-cascode

Comment: I know that was the closest topology to my circuit question so i asked why.

Comment: Are you sure that have you correctly redraw the circuit?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Is that for phase shift or current mirroring? I couldnt figure it out