# Question about cascode amplifier problem

Tags: cascode

The R<sub>out</sub> in the circuit below is stated by my textbook to be R<sub>out</sub> = [1 + g<sub>m2</sub>(r<sub>01</sub>||r<sub>π2</sub>)]r<sub>02</sub> + r<sub>01</sub>.

However, I thought the equation for R<sub>out</sub> was R<sub>out</sub> = [1 + g<sub>m2</sub>(r<sub>01</sub>||r<sub>π2</sub>)]r<sub>02</sub> + (r<sub>01</sub>||r<sub>π2</sub>) for a cascode amplifier.

What happened to the r<sub>π2</sub> in parallel with the r<sub>01</sub>?

[image]

Comment: And the book name is?

Comment: @G36 Problem 9.23 from Fundamentals of Microelectronics (2nd edition) by Behzad Razavi.

Comment: Well but you have a correct equation on page 396 and 397 (eq 9.1 and 9.5)

Comment: @G36 Yeah that was the one I mentioned in my question. I was just confused because the textbook provided the different equation for the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that \$R_{OUT} = g_{m2}r_{o2}(r_{\pi_2}||r_{o1}) + r_{o2} + r_{\pi_2}||r_{o1}\$

The proof can be found here:

[finding the output resistance of bjt folded cascode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380184/finding-the-output-resistance-of-bjt-folded-cascode/380228#380228)

Thus, if we collect in terms of \$r_{o2}\$ we will end up with this:

\$R_{OUT} = \left(1 + g_{m2}(r_{\pi_2}||r_{o1})\right)r_{o2} + r_{\pi_2}||r_{o1}\$

but we can collect in terms of \$r_{\pi_2}||r_{o1}\$ therefore:

\$R_{OUT} = (1 + g_{m2}r_{o2})\cdot r_{\pi_2}||r_{o1} + r_{o2}\$

Conclusion there is an error in the book equation but numerically not a big error.