# How to find the output impedance of a two BJT small signal circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

[image]

Like for instance, the picture above. How to find the output impedance?

My thought was like draw the small signal circuit of them, then do the equivalent. But I am not sure if I need to short the current source of Q2 or not. I know that for Q1, I need to short the current source, cause Vbe for Q1 is zero. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to short the current source?

Comment: Vbe for Q2 is also zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to short anything. In this schematic from a book (Behzad Razavi).

The GND symbol represents the AC ground, not a DC ground. 
Therefore you must assume that both transistors are properly biased. All, you need is to replace all transistor with the corresponding small-signal model and do the calculations.

Additional to simplify a thing notice that Q2 is work as a diode connected BJT.

And (I assumed that you read the book) you should know by now that the small-signal equivalent circuit for Q2 is a single "resistor" rd:

\$r_d = \frac{1}{gm}||r_\pi||r_o \approx \frac{1}{gm}\$

Hence your circuit reduced to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDiw5z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, you can look here:

[BJT common-base output resistance derivation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342859/bjt-common-base-output-resistance-derivation/342989#342989)

[Calculation of output impedance of CE emitter bias configuration( unbypassed) with r_0](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265046/calculation-of-output-impedance-of-ce-emitter-bias-configuration-unbypassed-wi/276764#276764)