# Measuring input and output resistance of the hybrid model

Tags: thevenin, small-signal

[image: diagram of hybrid model]

I understand that the input and output resistance is calculated using the Thevenins theorem. Thus the output resistance = Rc itself as the current source is open. But what about input resistance? Shouldn't it be (hi + Re)||Rb since the current source is open? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why would you open-circuit the collector?...doing so invalidates the whole amplifier. What about \$V_o\$? It should be shorted....then all of \$h_{fe}I_b\$ current flows through \$R_E\$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didnt short Vo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have a dependent source here (CCCS). So, you cannot turn it OFF, as we usually do with the "normal" (independent) current sources.

And \$R_{OUT} = R_C\$ is only true because when we are trying to find the output resistance we are setting/forcing the \$V_{IN}\$ to \$0V\$, hence no base current will flow due to input signal. And because your small-signal model do not contain \$h_{22} = h_{OE} = 1/ro\$. The dependent current source will be OFF in this case.

But if we add \$h_{22} = h_{OE}\$ the siutiation will be defrent.

See the example here:

[BJT common-base output resistance derivation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342859/bjt-common-base-output-resistance-derivation/342989#342989)

[Calculation of output impedance of CE emitter bias configuration( unbypassed) with r_0](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265046/calculation-of-output-impedance-of-ce-emitter-bias-configuration-unbypassed-wi/276764#276764)

[I/O Resistance of common source MOSFET with source degeneration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understood